# Android studio 3.2.1 create project with Api level 9

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I have an old tablet which I want to write a simple app for.

This tablet is working on android 2.3.7. Now the problem is I can't tell `android studio` to create a project for that exact android version.

I tried changing the `version`(Api level) manually but then I get some errors saying that: `other libraries require newer Api levels`.

I also installed the `SDK` version via the `sdk tools`.

Are there any solution to this problem?

Comment: This question suddenly reminds me of the time when we are using min 8 and target 11, with Eclipse + ADT... However, I just tried creating an app on Android Studio, then modify `min` and `target` to 8 and 11, it _works_ when syncing projects? (however I removed all libraries except Kotlin)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I deleted all the library references and now it syncs but it threw an error about the Theme so I changed it to the classic one. Now this error is gone but I get presented with a "failed linking ressources". In particuar it can't find the colors, defined in colors.xml
Was there another way to dfine them back then?

Comment: Manually define these colors? What do you mean?